# Android JSON POST Method

Tags: php, android, sql, jsonparser

Am a beginner in Android and am developing an App that fetches Data from SQL localhost(Temporary) server using a PHP script to get the desired table and extract fields. now all that is fine by following tutorials so i have a `ReyclerView` with `CustomAdapter` and am Using `LoaderManager` so I have a loader also that execute the fetchData Method in my `Utils Class` inside that Class there are the methods used to make the `HttpUrlConnection` till Extracting the JSON data from my SQL database and of to the `List<>` of my Model(Dish.Java) which contains the conductors and getter methods.

But now I am trying instead to send data to another table for example for items likes or rating for each item for that Purpose I created new Table which just contains likes as INT (later attach to the items with foreign key), accordingly I did search and found a PHP script (which fits my idiot case of fetching the data) as Follow:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

    require 'connection.php';

    updateLikes();

    }

    function updateLikes(){

        global $connect;
        $likes = $_POST['likes'];
        $query = "UPDATE likes SET likes = '$likes'";
        mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);

    }
?>
```

IF I try and make a `POST` Request not PUT on for example `Postman` am able to alter the likes field in my table. but no idea how am gonna add this to my query
so that for example taking the value of a `Ratingbar` after rating and accumulate it to the Server in the likes field (i know its ridiculous).
what I've found that i can make `setRequestMethod` for the `HttpUrlConnection` to "POST"  and use `DataOutputStream` like this:

```
class UpdateLikes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String URL = "http://localhost:81/likes.php";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String jsonData = params[0];
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        try {
            java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=" + charset);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            //send data
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(jsonData.toString());

            //OutputStream dos = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            //dos.write(Integer.parseInt(jsonData.toString()));

            //receive & read data response
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int byteCharacter;
            while ((byteCharacter = is.read()) != -1) {
                result.append((char) byteCharacter);
            }
            Log.d("json api", "DoUpdateProduct.doInBackground Json return: " + result);
            os.flush();
            is.close();
            os.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my code inside the ratingbar listener to execute the AsyncTask `doInBackground`

```
String counter = String.valueOf(rating);
                    Like likes = new Like(counter);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                    jsonObject.put("likes",likes.likes);
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                    Log.d("json api", "Json array converted from Product: " + jsonArray.toString());
                    String jsonData = String.valueOf(jsonArray);

                    new UpdateLikes().execute(jsonData);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e(MondayActivity.LOG_TAG, "Rating is:" + rating);
            }
        });
```

and then execute the thing is the when I Debugged I can get the rating and set it to the array, make the connection everything but it doesn't update anything in my database.

so any Recommendation how I can achieve this or maybe there is totally another way even to reconsider would be appreciated.

here are my classes so you have a look what's happenning

QuerUtils.Java

```
public class QueryUtils {
        public static long date;
        public static ArrayList<String> ls;

        public QueryUtils() {
        }

        private static URL createUrl(String strUrl) {
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL ", e);
            }
            return url;
        }

        private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {

            String jsonResponse = "";
            //TODO new
            if (url == null) {
                return jsonResponse;
            }
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the JSON results.", e);
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            if (inputStream != null) {

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    output.append(line);
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        public static List<Dish> fetchData(String requestUrl) {
          /*  try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    */
            URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

            String jsonResponse = "";

            try {
                jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
            }

            List<Dish> dishes = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "QueryUtils returns " + dishes);
            return dishes;
        }
        private static List<Dish> extractFeatureFromJson(String jsonResponse) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonResponse)) {
                return null;
            }

            List<Dish> dishes = new ArrayList<>();

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                JSONObject jsonObject1 = null;
                //dishes = new ArrayList<>();

                ls = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    if (jsonObject1 != null) {
                        String name = jsonObject1.getString("dish");
                        String daytime = jsonObject1.getString("daytime");
                        String dishName = jsonObject1.getString("dish");
                        String component = jsonObject1.getString("component");
                        double price = jsonObject1.getDouble("price");
                        String day = jsonObject1.getString("weakday");
                        int iconId_1 = jsonObject1.getInt("iconid_1");
                        int iconId_2 = jsonObject1.getInt("iconid_2");
                        date = jsonObject1.getLong("date");
                        int likesCounter = jsonObject1.getInt("likes");
                        String likes = String.valueOf((int) likesCounter);
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(date));

                        ls.add(jsonObject1.getString("date"));
                        Dish dish = new Dish(name, daytime, dishName,
                                component, price, day, date, iconId_1, iconId_2, likes);
                        dishes.add(dish);

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return dishes;
        }

    }
```

DishAdapterTest.java

```
  public class DishAdapterTest extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DishAdapterTest.ViewHolder> {
        private List<Dish> dishes;
        private Context context;

        public DishAdapterTest(Context context, List<Dish> dishes) {
            this.context = context;
            this.dishes = dishes;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public DishAdapterTest.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_dish, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Dish dish = dishes.get(position);
            holder.daytimeTextView.setText(dish.getmDayTime());

            holder.dishTextView.setText(dish.getmDish());
            holder.componentTextView.setText(dish.getmComponent());
            double originalPrice = dish.getmPrice();
            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
            String price = format.format(originalPrice);

            //String format2 = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00").format(dish.getmPrice());
            holder.priceTextView.setText(price);

            int icon_id = getIcon(dish.getmImageResId1());
            holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(icon_id);
            int icon_id2 = getIcon(dish.getmImageResId2());
            holder.icon1ImageView.setImageResource(icon_id2);
            holder.likesTextView.setText(dish.getmLikes());


            holder.mRatingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    Log.e(MondayActivity.LOG_TAG, "Rating is:" + rating);
                }
            });
        }

        public void setData(List<Dish> data) {
            dishes.clear();
            dishes.addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            Log.i("DishAdapter Mensa ", "dishes.size() = " + dishes.size());
            return dishes.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // The ViewHolder design pattern
            private TextView daytimeTextView;
            private TextView dishTextView;
            private TextView componentTextView;
            private TextView priceTextView;
            private ImageView iconImageView;
            private ImageView icon1ImageView;
            private RatingBar mRatingbar;
            private TextView likesTextView;


            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                this.daytimeTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.daytime_text_view);
                this.dishTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.dish_text_view);
                this.componentTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.component_text_view);
                this.priceTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
                this.iconImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view);
                this.icon1ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view1);
                this.mRatingbar = view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
                this.likesTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.likes_counter_text_view);
            }
        }
    }
```

Just in the main Activity related to this i have my adapter
i have my Loader overrided Method

```
@Override
    public Loader<List<Dish>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Initializing OnCreate Loader");
        if (dishList1.size() > 0) {
            dishList1.clear();
            dishAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return new DishLoader(this, REQUEST_URL);
    }

 @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Dish>> loader, List<Dish> dishes) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Initializing onFinished");
        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dishList1.clear();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Initializing onFinished Clear Adapter");
        if (dishes != null && !dishes.isEmpty()) {
            dishList1.clear();
            dishList1 = dishes;
            dishAdapter.setData(dishes);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check update query in your php script.

```
$query = "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = 'values', columnName = 'values' WHERE columnName = 'values';


$query = "UPDATE likes SET likes = '$likes'";
```

You forgotten `WHERE` clause.

Comment: so i tried this when i first approached the problem and now i tried it again and debugg i got this response :  Undefined index: likes in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\likes.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />. also i dont know should in php script specify the table name bec its not declared there just the field in the table and statement to update the field in the table.

Comment: you got this response because of the undefined symbol  '$likes'. you should refer this link for understand of UPDATE query https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: ok so i applied what u've said and add WHERE id atrr. now it works and go to the field and update it but set it to null and same response in log. i will update the json code above

Comment: Now check your android side what data you have to send to server. also check what value you have to pass. if you don't get any resolution then Please refer this link https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ hope it's useful for you.